# Pages with new chapters ignore pagestyle

Tags: chapters, books, pagestyle

I am currently working on a book and ran into a problem I was unable to solve so far.
It seems like whenever a new chapter is introduced, the current pagestyle is beeing ignored.
In my "mimnimal" working example one can see the overall definied header ("Header") is only shown on pages where no new chapter is starting. Also the pagenumber is no longer presented at the bottom of the page but at the top.
If you have any idea how to solve this or if and where it has already been solved please let know.

```
% Document class
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,english]{book}
% Geometry
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
% change in headheight needed otherwise poemscol produces warnings
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
% Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Fancy HDR
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Poem Typesetting
\usepackage{poemscol}
% Fill with text
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Chapters and Sections don't get a counter but still get into toc
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
% Page Layout
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
% Put the page number at the right edge of odd pages, and left edge of even pages.
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
% Custom text at the left edge of odd pages, and right edge of odd pages.
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Header}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Document Start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\title{This is a fancy book title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chap.1}
\section{Sec. 1.1}
    \lipsum
\subsection{Subsec. 1.1.2}
\begin{poem}
    \poemtitle{I don't have a clue}
    Roses are red \verseline
    Violets are blue \verseline
    I am writing a poem \verseline
    But I don't have a clue \verseline
\end{poem}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Sec. 1.2}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Chap.2}
\section{Sec 2.1}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec 2.2}
\section{Sec 2.3}
\section{Sec 2.4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see "redefining page style plain" in the fancyhdr documentation

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @UlrikeFischer mentioned in a comment, one must check the documentation of the used package.
As the package documentation for `fancyhdr` points out the command `\chapter` issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`.
Therefore a redefinition for the pagestyle plain is needed.
`\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrule}{}}` worked for me.

Comment: If you want to post Ulrike's comment as answer, then do that. But what you wrote is not an answer.